# How to set the GLFW OpenGL target?

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I'm programming on a Mac and I'm learning OpenGL in the library GLFW.

My problem is that my Mac supports OpenGL up to version 4.1, but when I try to compile the shaders with `version 410` it says `ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '410' is not supported`.

How do I set the version that GLFW should use?

Comment: you can use glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) to see which glsl versions are available to you. printf("Supported GLSL version is %s.\n", (char *)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));

Answer (score 1):

Changed the core profile to `3.2` by setting the window hints.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: Kinda looks like you changed it to `3.2`.

Comment: Well, in my code its 4.1 haha